unpaid bus fine, do I have problems?
I was in the Czech Republic in 2022 and I got a bus fine. Then I couldn't pay and forgot about it altogether. Now I found this fine and it still shows me the same amount, doesn't the fine amount increase after a month?
Can it not be forwarded to any enforcement agency? And I am also interested in how strictly the payment of these fines is controlled, I am not a citizen of a member state of the European Union

It's a guess, but the czech bus company has probably given up on getting those money. Enforcing it against someone who lives outside the EU (in many cases probably: outside the country) is probably so difficult/costly that it wouldn't pay off for them.

I was in other European countries during this period, but not in the Czech Republic. And now that the new law is introduced, won't it create a problem for me to enter other European countries?

Now I found this fine and it still shows me the same amount - Where did you find it?

"the new law is introduced", what new law? Many countries introduce new laws quite frequently.

It depends on who know it. It the bus company filled a complain to authorities, it may be there for some years (and immigration officers may see it). Else it is mostly a private affair between you and the company. (note on some countries fare fines are also stored in a more central database, independent if paid or not) to keep trace of recurring people who do not have valid tickets (I do not think it is the case in Czechia).

You ask if the fine increases after a month, but since 2022 a lot more than a month has elapsed.

In the Czech Republic, public transport fines, unlike driving fines, are not stored in any central database and are normally not reported to the authorities (such as the police). Each transport company has its own policy, but it mostly boils down to this: if the fine is not paid within a given time, the claim is sold to a law firm. The law firm then tries to get the money from the offender (they might even report you to the authorities) and if they succeed, they keep the money.
Since you're a non-EU foreigner, I suspect no law firm was willing to buy your case, because the chances of squeezing the money of out you are slim. In all likelihood, you have nothing to fear when you enter the EU or even the Czech Rep. That being said, why can't you simply pay the fine? It can't be a huge amount. And please buy a ticket next time...
